# Docker Image with volume - not displaying

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio

I'm trying to create my first docker image for a .Net 7 app, which saves files to a file location on the local machine. It works fine outside of Docker, but I need to change that to a docker volume, so that the files persist on the host machine.

So I want to reference `/app/imagestore` (Or maybe, just imagestore?) in my .Net code, so that it saves to `c:\storage\uploads\` on my host machine.

This is what I have in my docker-compose.override.yml file in my project.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  01.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - c:/storage/uploads:/app/imagestore:rw
```

But when I run it, the volume doesn't appear in Visual Studio (2022) as I'd expected.

[image]

I am trying to find an example of using Docker within Visual Studio online, but none seems to give an option for mapping volumes to host folders. How do I save files in my .Net 7 WebAPI project in Docker, to a host folder?